# Can a gear shifter be replaced?

Tags: brakes, gears

So I have a geared cycle from Rayleigh. While cycling I fell off, and the gear shifter for front gear broke off with the brake handle.

It was brand new cycle barely month old. and I didn't expect the cycle to be this fragile. Note that I was cycling at minimal speed, and not high speeds. The remaining gear shifter part is still hanging out.

Can it be replaced? And is it liable for warranty?

Comment: Yes, shifters can be replaced. No, no warranty covers damage by accidents.

Comment: The shifter will have a part number on it, or at least a brand name.  Can you identify that?   if not add some clear photos of the broken part.   Given your brake lever is also broken, it would be unsafe to ride this bike until it is fixed.   How many front and rear gears does your bike have ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, shifters can be replaced.  Given one shifter has already failed, you should consider replacing both.

Normally crash damage is not covered by warranty, though you could try asking the place where you bought the bike.

There is rarely a safe way to repair a brake component.  Once its broken, you should never trust it again.

I suspect you have a 3x7 drive train or similar, which is three chainrings at the front and 7 cogs in the rear wheel.  A set of replacement shifters like Shimano's ST-EF41 are probably suitable, though count them first.

https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney/ST-EF41-L.html

https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney/ST-EF41-R.html

---

Once you have the shifters, you will have to remove the inner cable that joins shifter to the derailleur.  Undo a pinch bolt on the derailleur and feed it back through.   If the inner cable is munched or has splayed ends, it may be easier to replace the inner cable with a new one at this time.  Your new shifter may come with one.

The brake cable is different - It is often possible to undo the brake cable without undoing it from the brake arms/caliper.

Then remove the hand grip, undo the handlebar clamp, and slide the old mech off the end.  Install the new one in the reverse process and adjust shifting till it works.

If you feel this is too hard for you, then ask the bike shop to fit the new shifter properly if you buy it from them.    Negotiate.   Good luck!